# Loading chunk 919 failed

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, react-router

[image]

Whenever I make a new deployment, I keep getting this error.

I discovered that this is a loading chunk Error

I have tried to resolve this by

- lazy loading the routes
- wrapping the App component Suspense,
- and also using Error Boundary

`<> <Suspense fallback={ <div> <Spinner /> </div> } > <ErrorBoundary> <RouterProvider router={routes(user)} /> </ErrorBoundary> </Suspense> </>`

None of the above has worked so far and I wonder if I need to use suspense and ErrorBoundary on each component being rendered and not the parent component (App)

Has anyone encountered this error, how did you resolve this?

Comment: What is your `output.publicPath` in `webpack.config.js`?  -- It should be pointed to `/your-dist/`

Comment: You should also include a bare minimum app with code, so we can duplicate your issue.   [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The project does not have a webpack.config.js. file, could this be a problem?

Also, I do not think it is a problem with the code. It is a regular react apps with different routes and pages that is deployed. Whenever I make a change and push to deployment, this error pops up

Comment: Without webpack.js .. It assumes that the entry point for your project is `src/index.js` --  Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, I assume in deployment, that will be build/index.js